# Resampling one data array from a dataset

Tags: python-3.x, dataset, resampling, python-xarray

I have this dataset - [snap of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBMlC.png). I want to resample **vcdtrop_no2**  to annual means. 
I tried `data['vcdtrop_n02'].resample(time=y).mean()` but the result doesn't keep the coordinates **lat** and **long**. Any idea how toe resample my date (from monthly to annual) but also to keep lat and long ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem will be fixed by writing:

```
data['vcdtrop_no2'].resample(time='Y').mean(dim='time')
```

When you use the `mean()`method, you should be specifying a dimension over which you want xarray to calculate the average.

Xarray's documentation here: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.mean.html#xarray.DataArray.mean, states that if the dimension is unspecified, the mean is calculated over all dimensions. In your case, that means that xarray averaged over the lat and long dimensions as well.

Hope that works for you!